# What collection and callback approach should I choose?

Tags: c++, boost, collections, callback

I have `map<string, COLLECTION>`. Each time the item is added to the COLLECTION it should be placed at position according to some condition. The reordering of the items should be automatically, I mean once I write something like `myVector.push_back(item)` the item should be placed at right position or replace the existing item based on some condition.

I thought to bind the `push_back` to some callback by `boost::bind`.

My questions are:

1. Is `bind` approach is good or there are some collections that allow to do it automatically?
2. What collection should I use?

Comment: It sounds like you want COLLECTION to be a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (if duplicates are NOT allowed) or a [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) (if duplicates ARE allowed). Both allow you to specify a custom comparison in multiple ways.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I want be able to add item if it answer condition1 and replace existing item if it answer condition2. I don't see how I do it with `std::set`

Comment: The duality of your conditions have nothing to do with *identity* nor *relational ordering*. Further the very definition you did provide will easily violate strict weak ordering, a condition mandated by the comparator of an ordered sequence using a canned container. So you're somewhat at the mercy of your own devices if that is the case.